# GitHub autodeploy node js app in Google cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, github, google-cloud-platform

I have successfully started my nodejs app (discord bot) in Google App engine and Google Compute Engine but i couldn't auto deploy the commits made on github

Is there and way to do those, so that if i commit a change the it should be updated in Google Cloud Programs

I tried Google open cloud source repositories but didn't work

Comment: Have you looked into GitHub Actions https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-appengine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried GitHub Actions as mentioned by @Ismail and it worked for me

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: Upload to Google Cloud App Engine

# Controls when the action will run. 
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the master branch
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Cloud SDK
        uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@master
        with:
          project_id: myid
          service_account_key: ${{ secrets.GCP_AUTHCode }}
          export_default_credentials: true

      - id: Deploy
        name: Deploy to App Engine
        uses: google-github-actions/deploy-appengine@main
        with:
          project_id: myid

      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 12
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm install pm2 -g
      - run: pm2 start index.js --watch
```

Answer (score 0):

You can automate App Engine deployments with Cloud Build. Study and follow this [GitHub App trigger](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/automating-builds/create-github-app-triggers) guide.

With regards to build configuration, you can use this sample build config file (cloudbuild.yaml):

```
steps:
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy"]
timeout: "1600s"
```

This configuration will make Cloud Build run `gcloud app deploy` on your repo whenever you push commits. The step will timeout if the deployment takes 27 minutes but you're free to change it.

As additional reference, [here's another guide](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart-triggering-builds-with-source-repositories) on how to  automate app deployment with Cloud Source Repositories.

To summarize, you need to enable Cloud Build on your project to use its trigger feature and it will build your app from source then deploy based on your build config.